# Search for specific values in a column and its corresponding data from rest of the columns

Tags: python, pandas, azure, databricks

I have following scenerio where I have to check for values in a column and its corresponding values in other columns. If any one of the value is not null then need to return true.
[image]

Suppose I have to check for values D, E and F in column1 and check its corresponding values in column2 and column3. Here column2 contains NaN but column3 contains data then return true

Comment: Can you be more specific about your output? Do you want to return True in another column or in a dictionary?

Comment: Actually this is a file data. So if D, E and F have any data other than NaN in its corresponding columns then I'll return its file path into a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, lets say you have the following data frame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({"Column1":['A','B','C','D'],'Column2':[1,2,3,np.nan],'Column3':['x','y',np.nan,np.nan]})
print(df)

  Column1  Column2 Column3
0       A      1.0       x
1       B      2.0       y
2       C      3.0     NaN
3       D      NaN     NaN
```

Then you should first set the column you want to check(Column1 in our case) as an index and do the following:

```
df.set_index('Column1').notna().any(axis=1)

Column1
A     True
B     True
C     True
D    False
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to test if [**`all`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) rows of the target have at least one non-NaN value ([**`any`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html)), use:

```
target = ['D', 'E', 'F']

out = (df.loc[df['Column1'].isin(target), ['Column2', 'Column3']]
         .notna().any(axis=1)
         .all()
      )
```

output: `True` (but would be `False` if `value1` was `NaN`)

If you want to check if there is at least one non-NaN cell, use `any` in both cases:

```
target = ['D', 'E', 'F']

out = (df.loc[df['Column1'].isin(target), ['Column2', 'Column3']]
         .notna().any(axis=1)
         .any()
      )
```

output: `True` (and would still be `True` if `value1` was `NaN`)